# Como lograr que un menú de opciones jerárquico funcione como una pila?

Tags: java, pilas

Necesito ayuda con un ejercicio que estoy realizando, ya que no logro saber como colocar el push y el pop de pila en un menú switch

Esta es mi **clase Pila**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LocalStack {

    private ArrayList<Object> data;

    public LocalStack(){

        this.data = new ArrayList<Object>();
    }

    public Object pop(){

        return data.remove(data.size()-1);
    }

    public boolean push(Object item){

        return data.add(item);
    }

    public void borrar(){

        this.data.clear();
    }

    public boolean vacio(){

        return this.data.isEmpty();
    }

}
```

Ahora quiero colocar en este menu esta clase anterior para que cuando necesite volver atras con alguna opcion me devuelva el valor anterior.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
int menu;
LocalStack revertir = new LocalStack();
Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

//codigo.....

do {
    System.out.println("Que deseas hacer:");    
    System.out.println("1) Opcion 1");
    System.out.println("2) Opcion 2");
    System.out.println("7) Salir");

    menu = lector.nextInt();

    switch(menu){
        case 1:
            revertir.push(1);
            System.out.println("opcion 1");

            do {
            System.out.println("3) Opcion 3");
            System.out.println("4) atras");
            System.out.println("7) Salir");
            menu = lector.nextInt();
            switch(menu){
            case 3:
                revertir.push(3);
                System.out.println("opcion 3");
                do {
                    System.out.println("5) Opcion 5");
                    System.out.println("6) atras");
                    System.out.println("7) Salir");
                    menu = lector.nextInt();
                    switch(menu){
                    case 5:
                        revertir.push(5);
                        System.out.println("opcion 5");
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        while (revertir.vacio());{
                        System.out.print(revertir.pop());
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("La opcion no es correcta"); 
                    }
                    }while(menu != 7);     
                break;
            case 4:
                while (revertir.vacio());{
                System.out.print(revertir.pop());
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("La opcion no es correcta"); 
            }
            }while(menu != 7);     
            break;
        case 2:
            revertir.push(2);
            System.out.println("opcion 2");

            do {
            System.out.println("3) Opcion 3");
            System.out.println("4) atras");
            System.out.println("7) Salir");
            menu = lector.nextInt();
            switch(menu){
            case 3:
                revertir.push(3);
                System.out.println("opcion 3");
                do {
                    System.out.println("5) Opcion 5");
                    System.out.println("6) atras");
                    System.out.println("7) Salir");
                    menu = lector.nextInt();
                    switch(menu){
                    case 5:
                        revertir.push(5);
                        System.out.println("opcion 5");
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        while (revertir.vacio());{
                        System.out.print(revertir.pop());
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("La opcion no es correcta"); 
                    }
                    }while(menu != 7);     
                break;
            case 4:
                while (revertir.vacio());{
                System.out.print(revertir.pop());
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("La opcion no es correcta"); 
            }
            }while(menu != 7);     
            break;
        default:
                System.out.println("La opcion no es correcta"); 
    }
    }while(menu != 7);
   }
 }
```

Esto es lo que hace el programa por consola:

```
Que deseas hacer:
1) Opcion 1
2) Opcion 2
7) Salir
1
opcion 1
3) Opcion 3
4) atras
7) Salir
4
13) Opcion 3
4) atras
7) Salir
```

Esto es lo que deberia hacer:

```
Que deseas hacer:
1) Opcion 1
2) Opcion 2
7) Salir
1
opcion 1
3) Opcion 3
4) atras
7) Salir
4
Opcion 1 // esto es lo que no me sale a mi
3) Opcion 3
4) atras
7) Salir
3
Opcion 3
5) Opcion 5
6) Atras
7) Salir
6
Opcion 3 // esto es lo que no me sale a mi
5) Opcion 5
6) Atras
7) Salir
5
Opcion 5
5) Opcion 5
6) Atras
7) Salir
6
Opcion 3  // esto es lo que no me sale a mi
3) Opcion 3
4) atras
7) Salir
4
Opcion 1  // esto es lo que no me sale a mi
```

Algo asi aprox (al pulsar atras vuelve al contenido anterior permitiendo volver atras en el menu)

En resumen

```
1 o 2
1
3 o atras
3
4 o atras
4
4 o atras
atras
3 o atras
atras
1 o  2
```

Comment: Divide y vencerás. Reorganiza tu código. Porque crees que existen propiedades , métodos, funciones en un lenguaje de programación. Estas en el camino pero tu  problema es querer hacer todo en un mismo método. Todos tus bloques switch-case deben ser metidos.  por ejemplo: e n el "main" tiene un menu de dos opciones y evalúa la opción ingresada: case 1: ProcesarOpcion1Menuprincipal y creas un método con este nombre y métodos que procesen el menu específico  y así vas desmenuzado. Vas a ver cómo se forma la pila cuando vayan retornando  de cada uno de ello.

Comment: Pero debo usar la clase LocalStack de esta forma la usaria?

Comment: No, porque realmente es un flujo. ¿es un requisito utilizar un stack? Porque allí entramos a un tema un poco más avanzado?

Comment: Dime si debes usar un stack, porque si es así, el esquema es otro y practicamentense podría hacer en un solo bloque pero habría que definir una estructura de dstos

Comment: si debo obligatoriamente usar el stack

Comment: Ok. Voy a hacer el esquema y estamos en contacto salvo que alguien más te dé el apoyo . Tengo que pasar a un desktop porque estoy en cel.

Comment: Vale :) Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Por favor, en todos los while  que tienen la condición (while menu!=7) modifcala para que quede ssi: while(menu!=7 && menu!=*) donde * es el número de la opción Atrás.:Prueba y me cuentas.

Comment: ya va hacia delante y hacia atras !!!!! oleeee!! ahora el problema es que me sale el numero de dentro del push y no el mensaje que quiero mostrar

Comment: Jajaja, pero realmente el stack es un saludo a la bandera  o es creo. De todas maneras  te voy a mostrar la versión con stack para que veas la diferencia. Si quitas el stack de tu código vas a ver que funciona. Si te fijas bien nunca asignas el valor del stack a una variable. Le has sacado la vuelta al stack.

Comment: Jajja vale, uff seria un gran favor si me enseñases como es con el stack

Answer (score -1, accepted):

te muestra como manejar un menu mediante una pila. Este ejemplo utiliza java 1.8 y al menos va a mostrarte como funciona el stack.  Utilizo la clase Stack del java. No me hago problemas creando mi propia clase. Ahora si quieres adaptarlo a tu stack, entonces, te queda como tarea.

Como sabes el stack es una cola "Ultimo en entrar, primero en Salir". Por lo tanto, antes de ir a un menu de nivel inferior ponemos en el stack el menu actual. Si en este nuevo menu existe una opción hacia otro menu, al igual que el anterior, ponemos el menu en el stack y activamos el nuevo menu. Aquí cabe señalar que ahora habrían dos menu en el stack. Hacemos lo anterior siempre que bajamos de nivel. Cuando se retorna del submenu se obtiene de la pila el ultimo menu (por la característica del stack).

```java
package com.menustatck;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class MenuStack {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new MenuStack().Procesar();
    }

    public void Procesar() {

        // Clase que representa una opción del menu
        // Solo soporta navegación   entre menús.
        class MenuItem {
            int opcion; // Opcion que el usuario debe ingresar
            String titulo; // Descripción de la opción
            int menuSgte; // Indice del menu (listaMenu) que debe mostrarse 
            public MenuItem(int opcion, String titulo, int menuSgte) {
                this.opcion = opcion;
                this.titulo = titulo;
                this.menuSgte = menuSgte;
            }
        };

        // Menú de opciones 
        class Menu {
            Scanner _in = new Scanner(System. in ); // Lectura desde consola.
            int selected;
            String titulo; // titulo del menu en la parte superior
            Boolean esSubMenu; // Si es verdadero, entonces, este no es el principal.
            List < MenuItem > menuItems = null; // Lista de opciones que mostrará este menu-
            public Menu(String titulo, Boolean esSubMenu, MenuItem[] menuItems) {
                this.titulo = titulo;
                this.menuItems = new ArrayList < MenuItem > ();
                this.menuItems.addAll(Arrays.asList(menuItems));
                this.esSubMenu = esSubMenu;
                if (esSubMenu) {
                    this.menuItems.add(new MenuItem(6, "Regresar", 0));
                }
                this.menuItems.add(new MenuItem(7, "Salir", 0));
            }

            public MenuItem mostrarMenu() {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("**** " + this.titulo + "******");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------");
                this.menuItems.forEach(item - >System.out.printf("%d. %s\n", item.opcion, item.titulo));
                System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------");
                MenuItem menuSelected = null;
                do {
                    System.out.print(" Opción ? ");
                    this.selected = _in.nextInt();
                    try {
                        menuSelected = menuItems.stream().filter(mi - >mi.opcion == this.selected).findFirst().get();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Opcion inválida!");
                    }
                } while ( menuSelected == null );

                return menuSelected;
            }
        }

        /* Menus */

        final Menu[] listaMenus = new Menu[] {
            new Menu("Menu Principal", false, new MenuItem[] {
                new MenuItem(1, "Opcion 1", 1
                /* Va al Menu Opcion 1*/
                ),
                new MenuItem(2, "Opcion 2", 2
                /* Va al Menu Opcion 2 */
                )
            }),
            new Menu("Menu Opcion 1", true, new MenuItem[] {
                new MenuItem(3, "Opcion 3", 3
                /* Va al Menu Opcion 3 */
                ),
                new MenuItem(5, "Opcion 5", 5
                /*  Va al Menu Opcion 3*/
                )
            }),
            new Menu("Menu Opcion 2", true, new MenuItem[] {
                new MenuItem(5, "Opcion 5", 5
                /*  Va al Menu Opcion 5*/
                )
            }),
            new Menu("Menu Opcion 3", true, new MenuItem[] {
                new MenuItem(4, "Opcion 4", 4
                /*  Va al Menu Opcion 4*/
                )
            }),
            new Menu("Menu Opcion 4", true, new MenuItem[] {
                new MenuItem(5, "Opcion 5", 0
                /* No hace nada  */
                )
            }),
            new Menu("Menu Opcion 5", true, new MenuItem[] {
                new MenuItem(3, "Opcion 3", 3
                /*  Va al Menu Opcion 3*/
                )
            })
        };

        // Pila para ir colocando los menus por donde vamos pasando
        Stack < Menu > st = new Stack < Menu > ();

        // Inicia con el menu principal
        Menu menuActual = listaMenus[0];

        MenuItem opcion = null;

        do {
            //  Mostrar menu y retornar el menuitem seleccionado
            opcion = menuActual.mostrarMenu();
            // retroce al menu anterior si no estamos en el menu principal
            if (opcion.opcion == 6 && menuActual.esSubMenu) {
                // Recupera el menu anterior del stack y lo pone como activo
                menuActual = st.pop();
            }
            else if (opcion.opcion != 7) {
                // Para cualquier opción que tenga que navegar a otro menu
                if (opcion.menuSgte != 0) {
                    // Antes de activar el nuevo menu  
                    // Guardo  éste en el stack
                    st.push(menuActual);
                    // Obtengo el nuevo menú que será el menu activo
                    menuActual = listaMenus[opcion.menuSgte];
                }
            }
            else {
                // Si es 7 y es un sub menu retorna al menu principal
                if (menuActual.esSubMenu) {
                    menuActual = listaMenus[0];
                    opcion.opcion = 0;
                    // Limpia stack porque estamos en el menu principal
                    st.clear();;
                }
            }
        } while ( opcion . opcion != 7 );

    }
}
```

Comment: Observación: Lo que señalas es falso: *Como sabes el stack es una cola "Ultimo en entrar, primero en Salir"* Un stack(pila) es un LIFO pero la cola es un FIFO(first input first output) por lo que la pila no es como una cola.

Comment: Tu dices: *stack es una cola*, pues no, es lo contrario: mientras en la cola el primero que entra es el primero que sale en un stack(pila) el primero que entra es el último que sale.

Comment: Stack en castellano es pila. Y que es la pila: una lista. Igual que es una cola: también una lista. Sin embargo, dependiendo de la característica de esta lista las llamamos Stack, Queue. Sin embargo, tengo que mejorar la redacción

Comment: Entiendo lo que señalas pero tu redacción es muy confusa :-). Por ejemplo ¿Era necesario señalar lo de la cola? IMHO no, bastaba con señalar: **Una pila (*Stack*) tiene como caracteristica que el último elemento en entrar es el primero en salir.**

Comment: Tu observación es buena, pero cuando digo pila o cola no me estoy refiriendo a la clase o tipo. Me refiero a Stack. Si hubiera sido una cola hubiera puesto Queue,.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Porque me permite mejorar la redacción  voy a editar la para mejorarla. Gracias nuevamente

Comment: Otra mejora es publicar un código bien formateado(por ejemplo ya edite tu pregunta con esa mejora).

Comment: Lo que pasa es que muchas veces contesto del celular y salen estas cosas. Voy a tomar nota de esto para no escribir por celular respuestas  grandes. Muchas Gracias!!!

Comment: Tomate el tiempo necesario para publicar y mejorar si deseas obtener una pregunta de calidad.

Comment: Hola!! Muchisimas gracias por vuestra ayuda! no sabia si dar la respuesta por buena después de ver la puntuacion de la respuesta pero leyendo lo que comentais creo que queda claro y la doy por buena muchisimas gracias!